# Problema para actualizar tabla de BD con JAVA/Struts leyendo excel con POI

Tags: java, excel, oracle, struts

Amigos de la comunidad, estoy desarrollando un modulo que lee/carga un archivo excel y su contenido lo debe guardar en variables (en el Action) para luego llamar a un SP que realiza un update en la tabla de la base de datos.

El problema es que utilizando POI lee el archivo, genera la lista de datos a enviar al SP, se recibe respuesta del SP indicando correcto, sin embargo al hacer la consulta en la tabla el update no fue realizado.

Si genero la lista con datos en duro y la paso al SP se realiza el update correctamente.

Que puede estar fallando?

PD: por razones de confidencialidad no puedo subir el codigo. Lo intentare tal vez.

Adjunto codigo del Action que lee el archivo excel, y pasa los valores a las variables titulo, codigo y usuario, las cuales concatena en una linea y lista (si viene mas de 1 fila en el excel) la cual envia al SP que actualiza la tabla.

---

```
  public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,

                             HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException, SQLException  {

    Log.info("RealizarUpdateAction inicio Action");

    InputStream is = null;
    Sheet sheet = null;
    int rows = 0;

    RealizarUpdateActionForm f = (RealizarUpdateActionForm) form;
    User    doingUsr= null;
    doingUsr    = (Usuarios) request.getSession().getAttribute("UsuariosSesion");
    String pkuser  = doingUsr.getPkUser();

    FormFile archivo = f.getFileupload();
    ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();

    CallableStatement proc    = null;
    String procedure = "";
    String mensaje = "";
    Connection con = Pool.getInstancia().getConnection();

    int estado = 0;     

    String titulo       = "";
    String codigo       = "";
    String usuario      = "";
    String lista        = "";
    String linea        = "";



    if (archivo != null && !archivo.toString().equals("")) {

        String extension = archivo.toString().substring(archivo.toString().lastIndexOf("."));
        String tipoArchivo = "excel";

        if (!FormatoArchivo.extArchivo(extension, tipoArchivo)) {
              errors.add("errorarchivo", new ActionError("error.mensaje", "Archivo no es Excel."));
        }else{
            int i = 0;
            try{
                is = archivo.getInputStream();
                Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(is);
                sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
                rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();                            

                for (i = 1; i < rows; i++){
                    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row row = sheet.getRow(i);                       
                    Cell cell_titulo          = row.getCell(0);
                    Cell cell_codigo           = row.getCell(1);
                    Cell cell_usuario        = row.getCell(2);                      

                    cell_titulo.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    cell_codigo.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    cell_usuario.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);

                    titulo           = cell_titulo.getStringCellValue();
                    codigo          = cell_codigo.getStringCellValue();
                    usuario       = cell_usuario.getStringCellValue();                      

                    if(i > 0){  
                        linea = titulo+","+codigo+","+usuario;
                    }
                    if(i == 1){
                        lista = linea;
                    }else if (i > 1){
                        lista = lista+";"+linea;
                    }                   
                }                
            }catch(Exception e){
                //Log.info("Ocurrio la siguiente excepcion : " + e.getMessage()); 
                if(i==1){
                    Log.info("RealizarUpdateAction error: Archivo no contiene datos para procesar.");
                    return mapping.findForward("error");
                }else{
                    Log.info("RealizarUpdateAction error "+e.getMessage()); //arroja un nullPointerException dado que llega al ultimo registro en el excel y no tiene datos
                }
            }

            // Llamado al SP para procesar los datos
            try{
                procedure = "{call SP_UPD_TABLATITULOS (?,?,?,?)}";
                proc = con.prepareCall(procedure);
                proc.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
                proc.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
                proc.setString(1,lista);
                proc.setInt(2,Integer.valueOf(pkuser));
                proc.executeUpdate();
                estado   = proc.getInt(3);
                mensaje  = proc.getString(4);
            }catch(SQLException e){
                Log.info("RealizarUpdateAction.cargarArchivo.proc Exception =  "+e.getMessage());
            }

            if(estado == 0){
                request.setAttribute("DATOSUPD","TRUE");
                con.close(); 
                return mapping.findForward("ok");
            }else if(estado == 1){
                request.setAttribute("DATOSUPD","FALSE");
                request.setAttribute("MENSAJE",mensaje);
                con.close(); 
                return mapping.findForward("ok");
            }                                     
        }
    }      
    return mapping.findForward("ok");
}
```

Comment: no es claro qué problema tiene. lea: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Estimado, adjunté el código del Action que realiza la lectura del excel, por si es de utilidad para entender el problema. Adicionalmente quiero agregar que al ejecutar el sistema y cargar el excel, el SP devuelve valor 0 (todo ok), sin embargo al consultar directamente la tabla el cambio no fue realizado. Si ejecuto el SP como TestSQL funciona correctamente la actualizacion, por lo que el SP funciona. Una prueba que hice fue modificar el Action, quitar la lectura del excel mediante POI, y generando la lista con datos en duro, ejecuté la aplicacion y SI realizó el update en la tabla.

Comment: No se entiende muy bien qué exactamente estás haciendo pero, si es posible, explícanos qué son cell_gift, cell_dni y cell_nombre porque no se ven definidas por ningún sitio. Tampoco está claro qué son cell_titulo/codigo/usuario.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev los campos cell_gift/dni/nombre estaban incorrectos, debian ser cell_titulo/codigo/nombre. Estos son los que hacen referencia a cada columna en el archivo excel. Con los valores que se toman de cada celda del excel se forma una cadena string (concatenando titulo,codigo,nombre:titulo,codigo,nombre...) la cual se envia al SP que desgloza la cadena y actualiza la tabla eb la BD. El código SI lee los datos y genera la cadena, sin embargo no actualiza la BD. El SP si funciona al ejecutar como test.

Comment: Bien, así cuadra más. Otra cosa - me imagino que no tienes excepciones pero ¿en este caso no debes hacer commit? No lo sé, pregunto. Y solo como recomendación - pon `con.close();` en un bloque *finally* después del catch de SQLException.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev, En el SP se realiza el commit al realizarse correctamente el update, y envia un 0 (todo OK) que recibe JAVA, sin embargo el update no se realiza. Sobre el cierre de la conexion lo estoy aplicando tal como comentas, aca tal vez lo quité sin querer. Mira, para aclarar son 3 casos: 1.- El codigo tal cual está acá lee el excel y envia la lista al SP que responde Todo OK pero no actualiza la tabla. 2.- Ejecutar el SP por si solo con una cadena con datos en duro realiza correctamente el update. 3.- en JAVA no leer los datos del excel y enviar datos en duro al SP si realiza el update.